# Attaching already created database (.sqlite) with xcdatamodel

Tags: core-data

I have created a data base (.sqlite) using SQLiteManager plugin for firefox,now I want those tables to be attached with the .xcdatamodel created in my iPhone project.Though I am able to create the Entity using the xcode, but dont know how to enter entries in this database ,so I have used firefox plugin to enter database entries.I have wasted hours of efforts for entering the records ,I dont want to create that again programmatically offcourse more data may be added later programmatically.

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly advised that you do *NOT* directly edit the sqlite store. It is a proprietary schema with lots of details only the Core Data framework knows.

If you want to manually input data to a store with a model you already created, i recommend using [Core Data Editor](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/core-data-editor/id403025957?mt=12), available on the Mac App Store

Comment: Thanks a lot ,Core Data Editor seams what I want .... though I have added the data by code itself ..... I will surely look at Core Data Editor.